# Find gaps in auto incremented values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Imagine having a table as the one below:

```
create table test (
   id int auto_increment, 
   some int, 
   columns int
)
```

And then this table get used alot. Rows are inserted and rows are deleted and over time there might be gaps in the number that once was auto incremented. As an example, if I at some point make the following query:

```
select top 10 id from test
```

I might get something like

```
3
4
6
7
9
10
13
14
18
19
```

How do I design a query that returns the missing values 1,2,5,8 etc?

Comment: Take a look at this article: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to get *ranges* of missing values:

```
select (id + 1) as firstmissing, (nextid - 1) as lastmissing
from (select t.id, lead(id) over (order by id) as nextid
      from test t
     ) t
where nextid is not null and nextid <> id + 1;
```

Note this uses the `lead()` function, which is available in SQL Server 2012+.  You can do something similar with `apply` or a subquery in earlier versions.  Here is an example:

```
select (id + 1) as firstmissing, (nextid - 1) as lastmissing
from (select t.id, tt.id as nextid
      from test t cross apply
           (select top 1 id
            from test t2
            where t2.id > t.id
            order by id
           ) tt
     ) t
where nextid is not null and nextid <> id + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is by using cte..

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT 1 id
         UNION ALL
         SELECT id + 1 id from cte
         WHERE  id < (SELECT Max(id)
                      FROM   tablename))
SELECT *
FROM   cte
WHERE  id NOT IN(SELECT id
                 FROM   tablename)
```

**Note:** this will start from 1. If you want start from the min value of your table just replace

```
"SELECT 1 id" to "SELECT Min(id) id FROM   tablename"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why does it matter? I'm not trying to be snarky, but this question is usually asked in the context of "I want to fill in the gaps" or "I want to compress my id values to be contiguous". In either case, the answer is "don't do it". In your example, there was at some point a row with id = 5. If you're going to do either of the above, you'll be assigning a different, unrelated set of business data that id. If there's anything that references the id external to your database, now you've just invented a problem that you didn't have before. The id should be treated as immutable and arbitrary for all intents and purposes. If you really require it to be gapless, don't use identity and never do a hard delete (i.e. if you need to deactivate a row, you need a column which says whether it's active or not).

Comment: Though I'm with you, this is more a comment than an answer.

Comment: I considered that, but this is a common enough question and this is the answer to that question. Not every problem is a technical one. But, if you feel strongly about it, use the down arrow to take away some of my internet points.

Comment: Neither flagging nor voting just noting

Comment: Just to give an answer to your question. The project I had this problem in has a bad design. The values in the tables can't by any means have any gaps and the one who created this based these numbers on auto_increment'ed numbers. Naturally, I want to know if this design have caused any problems over the years without having to check every row in the databse manually :)